# How do I use replace with capture group?

Tags: julia

I want to add two tab-divisions into a tsv file after First+Last name (`\nJohn Smith\t`) occurrence:

```
dl=readstring(fileName)
dl=replace(dl,r"(\n[A-Za-z\s]+\t)","\1\t\t")
```

I get First+Last Name replaced by `x01`. The docs say something about substitution string but I can't find the implementation

Update: this substitutes for a group

```
dl=replace(dl,r"(\n[A-Za-z\s]+\t)",s"\1")
```

But this:

```
dl=replace(dl,r"(\n[A-Za-z\s]+\t)",s"\1\t\t")
```

results in an error `Bad Replace`. Symbols without `\` seem fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like bug to me. But you could use workaround:

```bash
julia> dl = "\nJohn Smith\t";
julia> s = Base.SubstitutionString;
julia> dl=replace(dl, r"(\n[A-Za-z\s]+\t)", s("\\1\t"))
"\nJohn Smith\t\t"
```

**edit:**

I think this is better:

```sh
julia> dl = "\nJohn Smith\t";
julia> dl=replace(dl, r"(\n[A-Za-z\s]+\t)", @s_str("\\1\t"))
"\nJohn Smith\t\t"
```

BTW if you want to append number after capture group then you could do other trick (named groups):

```bash
julia> replace("aAa", r"(?<one>A+)", s"\g<one>1")
"aA1a"
```